# Componente Auth do Cakephp 3 não funciona

Tags: cakephp, auth, authorization

Estou com problemas no componente de autorização do cake, fiz vários testes e ele é único componente que não esta funcionando, já verifiquei autorização do banco, e possuo autorização normalmente, já reinstalei todo meu sistema do 0 e fazer novo projeto mas o problema permanece, já verifiquei os valores dos meus campos de de senha e username e estão corretos, já fiz teste com a senha criptografada e não criptografada e nada também.

Estou faz semanas tentando resolver o problema e não acho nenhuma solução na internet e nem na documentação que possa me ajudar.
Unica solução e acho que pode ter, ao meu ver, é forçar uma requisição na model para fazer a autorização sem usar o componente nativo, porém não estou conseguindo utilizar a query do proprio cake para fazer isso.
Segue meu código

AppController

```
namespace App\Controller;
use Cake\Controller\Controller;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Core\Configure;

class AppController extends Controller
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        /*parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler', [
            'enableBeforeRedirect' => false,
        ]);*/
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'fields' => [
                        'username' => 'username',
                        'password' => 'password'
                    ]

                ]
            ],
            'loginRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Pagprincipal',
                'action' => 'index'
            ],
            'logoutRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Pagprincipal',
                'action' => 'login'
            ]
        ]);

    }

    public function beforeFilter(Event $event) 
    {
        $this->Auth->allow(['index', 'view']);

    }
}
```

UserController

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public function login()
    {
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            if('Users'){
                $this->Auth->setUser('Users');
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }else{ 
                $this->Flash->error(__('Username ou senha inválidos, tente novamente!'));
            }   

        }
    }
```

Login.ctp

```
<div>
<?= $this->Flash->render('auth') ?>
<?= $this->Form->create() ?>

    <div>
        <form>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->control('username');
            echo $this->Form->control('password');
        ?>
            <p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" <?php if(isset($_COOKIE["member_login"])) { ?> checked <?php } ?> />
                <label for="remember-me">Lembrar</label>
            </p>
        </form>
            <button>Entrar</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri que muitas coisas do cake no meu pc parou de funcionar, como o componente Auth, por isso achei uma solução para poder fazer autorização do meu usuário sem utilizar o componente. Minha solução foi fazer a busca e autorização tudo na mão, sem utilizar o componente Auth.

AppController

```
public function initialize()
{
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'username',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ]

            ]
        ],
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Pagprincipal',
            'action' => 'index'
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Pagprincipal',
            'action' => 'login'
        ],
        //'authorize' => array('Controller')
    ]);
}
```

UserController

```
public function login()
{

    $usuario = null;
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

        $username = addslashes($_POST['username']);
        $password = addslashes($_POST['password']);

        $user = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Users');
        $query = $user
                    ->find()
                    ->where([
                        'username' => $username,
                        'password' => $password
                    ]);
        $results = $query->toArray();
        if(isset($results[0])){
            $name = $results[0]["name"];
            $idUsuario = $results[0]["id"];
            $this->Auth->setUser($results[0]);
            $_SESSION['usuarioLogado'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['nomeUsuario'] = $name;
            $_SESSION['idUsuarioLogado'] = $idUsuario;

            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
    }

    if($this->Auth->User){
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
    }

    $this->set('usuario', $usuario);
```

Login.ctp

```
<body class="login">
    <?= $this->Flash->render('auth') ?>
    <?= $this->Form->create() ?>

    <?php 

    if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

        if($usuario == false){
            echo "<div style='padding:10px;text-align:center;'><b>Usuário ou senhas inválidos!</b></div>";
        } 

    }
    ?>

    <div class="logindiv">
        <form>
        <?php
            //echo $this->Form->control('Username:', ['type'=>'username']);
            echo $this->Form->control('username');
            echo $this->Form->control('password');
        ?>
            <p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" 
                <?php if(isset($_COOKIE["member_login"])) { ?> checked <?php } ?> />
                <label for="remember-me">Lembrar</label>
            </p>
        </form>
        <button class="loginbuttom" type="Submit">Entrar</button>
    </div>
</body>
```